# Backbone back button scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone and everything was going well before decided to preserve 
scrollTop position between a long list of items and an item view. I managed to 
save the scroll position of the list and item view and everything is fine but when pressing the browser back button there is an autoscrolling from the browser going back to the position of the listView  before actually going back to the list view. I googled and found nothing about this behavior. Is there any solution to this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
App.prototype.initialize = function() {
  var e, error1, fallbackLanguage, language;
  L.debug("App.initialize -> triggered.");
  try {
    Backbone.noConflict();
    _.noConflict();
    window.app = {};
    window.app.scrollYHistory = {};
    window.app.history = [];
    this.listenTo(Backbone, "translate", _translate);
    this.listenTo(Backbone, "changeLanguage", _changeLanguage);
    this.listenTo(Backbone, "setServerLanguage", _setServerLanguage);
    this.listenTo(Backbone, "userLoggedOut", _destroyJWT);
    this.listenTo(Backbone, "setJWT", _setJWT);
    this.listenTo(Backbone.history, "route", _history);
    _UASupportAnimation();
    _UASupportCookie();
    _UASupportLocalStorage();
    _UASupportTransition();
    _cssExtra();
    window.onerror = function(error) {
      return L.error(error);
    };
    new MainRouter();
    new UserRouter();
    new AdminRouter();
    fallbackLanguage = LANGUAGE_SUPPORTED[LANGUAGE_DEFAULT];
    language = _getLanguage();
    L.debug("App.initialize -> i18n module.");
    return $.i18n.init({
      "useCookie": false,
      "fallbackLng": fallbackLanguage,
      "lng": language,
      "load": "current",
      "ns": {
        "namespaces": ["translation", "validation"],
        "defaultNs": "translation"
      },
      "resGetPath": "/static/languages/__lng__/__ns__.json",
      "useDataAttrOptions": true
    }).done(function() {
      L.debug("App.initialize -> i18n initialization done, starting the application.");
      _setServerLanguage();
      Backbone.history.start({
        "root": "/",
        "pushState": true,
        "hashChange": true
      });
      return L.debug("App.initialize -> initialization completed.");
    });
  } catch (error1) {
    e = error1;
    return L.error(e);
  }
};
_history = function(router, handler, args) {
  var e, error1, lastPage;
  try {
    lastPage = window.app.history[window.app.history.length - 1];
    if (!_.isUndefined(lastPage)) {
      _saveScrollYPosition(lastPage);
    }
    return window.app.history.push(window.location.pathname);
  } catch (error1) {
    e = error1;
    return L.error(e);
  }
};

_saveScrollYPosition = function(pathname) {
  var e, error1;
  try {
    L.debug("App._saveScrollYPosition -> triggered.");
    return window.app.scrollYHistory[pathname || window.location.pathname] = document.body.scrollTop;
  } catch (error1) {
    e = error1;
    return L.error(e);
  }
};



function AdView() {
  return AdView.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

AdView.prototype.tagName = "section";

AdView.prototype.className = "l-page l-page--ad";

AdView.prototype.template = _.template($(Template).html());

AdView.prototype.initialize = function(model) {
  var e, error;
  this.model = model;
  if (!this.model) {
    throw new Error("adView.initialize -> can't initialize without my model!");
  }
  try {
    this.Header = HeaderView;
    this.Footer = FooterView;
    this.adModel = this.model.adModel.toJSON();
    this.scrollYPosition = window.app.scrollYHistory[window.location.pathname] || 0;
    this.compiledTemplate = this.template(this.adModel);
    return L.debug((this.getMyName()) + ".initialize -> done.");
  } catch (error) {
    e = error;
    return L.error(e);
  }
};

AdView.prototype.render = function() {
  var e, error;
  L.debug((this.getMyName()) + ".render -> triggered");
  try {
    $("main").html(this.$el.html(this.compiledTemplate));
    window.scroll(0, this.scrollYPosition);
    L.debug((this.getMyName()) + ".render -> process completed.");
    return this;
  } catch (error) {
    e = error;
    return L.error(e);
  }
};
return AdView;
```

Comment: You might get more feedback if you can post the minimum sample of code needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Updated with some code. Actual code is written in coffescript. Thanks Barett, this is my first post.

Comment: If I knew Backbone, I'd be all over this. I'll upvote instead. Wish I could be of more help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AdView.prototype.render` method you have `window.scroll(0, this.scrollYPosition);`.   It's not clear from the provided code where `AdView.prototype.render` gets called, but presumably something in your routing logic calls it when the user visits the route.

You wrote :

> when pressing the browser back button there is an autoscrolling from
>   the browser going back to the position of the listView before actually
>   going back to the list view

When you click the browser's back  button that triggers a new routing operation,  so it re-triggers that routing logic.  Since your `render` logic involves changing the `window`'s scroll position, it's only natural that when you click the back button you will re-trigger that `render`, which will re-change the scroll position.

Comment: Hi machineghost, thanks for looking at this old question. I have moved on since but you are probably right, AdView.render was called somewhere from the router logic.